# How to find a word - First letter will be capital & other will be lower

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Problem Statement: Filter those words from the complete set of text6, having first letter in upper case and all other letters in lower case. Store the result in variable title_words. print the number of words present in title_words.

I have tried every possible ways to find the answer but don't know where I am lagging.

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import text6
title_words = 0
for item in set(text6):
    if item[0].isupper() and item[1:].islower():
        title_words += 1
print(title_words)
```

I have tried in this way as well:

```
title_words = 0
for item in text6:
    if item[0].isupper() and item[1:].islower():
        title_words += 1
print(title_words)
```

I am not sure how many count its required, whatever the count is coming its not allowing me to pass the challenge. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in this code

Comment: Have you tried printing out some of the `item`s in `set(text6)`? What about printing some of them and whether or not your `if` condition was true or false. Control+C and look through it manually to see if it's behaving as you would expect. (What about words that  are just punctuation?)

Comment: @khelwood, :( I have tried to append those items in list and checked the list manually but its not working. Is anything wrong in my code or I am missing something big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `set(text6)`. I suggest you iterate over `text6.tokens`.

**Update, explanation**

The code you've provided is correct.

The issues is that the text can contain same words multiple times. Doing a `set(words)` will reduce the total available words, so you start with an incomplete data set.

The other responses are not necessary wrong in checking the validity of a word, but they are iterating over the same wrong data set.

Comment: @Lucifer I've updated the answer with an explanation. Hope it helps you! :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the above suggestions did work for me. Sample code below.

```
title_words = [word for word in text6 if (len(word)==1 and word[0].isupper()) or (word[0].isupper() and word[1:].islower()) ]
print(len(title_words))
```

Comment: what did you mean with "above suggestions" ? There is nothing above in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, "Store the result in variable title_words. print the number of words present in title_words."

The result of filtering a list of elements is a list of the same type of elements. In your case, filtering the list `text6` (assuming it's a list of strings) would result in a (smaller) list of strings. Your `title_words` variable should be this filtered list, not the number of strings; the number of strings would just be the length of the list.

It's also ambiguous from the question if capitalized words should be *filtered out* (ie. removed from the smaller list) or *filtered* (ie. kept in the list), so try out both to see if you're interpreting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Give regular expressions a try:

```
>>> import re
>>> from nltk.book import text6
>>>
>>> text = ' '.join(set(text6))
>>> title_words = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)', text)
>>> len(title_words)
461
```

Comment: Thanks @constt for continiuos effort & update. Appreciate it. But still its not passing the challenge. Believe me I copy pasted the challenge without any edit. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 50 singleton elements (elements of length one) in text6, however, your code would not pass any as a success, like, 'I' or 'W' etc. Is that correct, or do you require words of minimum length 2?

Comment: :( Tried that as well len(item) > 1 or 2 but still no help. Sometimes I think its better to give up. :) From lot of days I am trying & today I tried with all the folks here but its not passing. :) Thanks Brother. I am giving up now.

Comment: Did you try to include all words of length=1, that is also capitalised? No worries if you are moving on however, take care.

Answer (score 0):

Just few changes according to what the question asks.

```
from nltk.book import text6
title_words = []
for item in set(text6):
    if item[0].isupper() and item[1:].islower():
        title_words.append(item)
print(len(title_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
title_words = [ word for word in text6 if word.istitle()]

print(len(title_words))
```