# How to find a words - First letter will be capital & other will be lower

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Filter those words from the complete set of text6, having first letter in upper case and all other letters in lower case. Store the result in variable title_words. print the number of words present in title_words.

i'm facing the same problem as the below link,

[How to find a word - First letter will be capital & other will be lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438634/how-to-find-a-word-first-letter-will-be-capital-other-will-be-lower)

no answers are accepted in the challenge.

neither 2341 or 461.

Comment: What is your question (that isn't answered on the linked webpage)? Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I've answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156741/11788678 Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
title_words = []
for item in set(text6):
    if item.istitle():
        title_words.append(item)
print(len(title_words))
```

Or more pythonic:

```
title_words = [x for x in set(text6) if x.istitle()]
print(len(title_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check(word):
   if(word[0].isupper()==True and word[1:len(word)].islower()==True):
        return word
   else:
        return False
print(check("App"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## for update we can use input but in online compiler it throws eof erorr

def check(word):
   if(word[0].isupper()==True and word[1:len(word)].islower()==True):
        return word
   else:
        return False
text6=set()
text6.update(["word","App","Jsk"])
for i in text6:

```
print(check(i))
```